# touchEvent.touches.length returns always 1 on Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, touch-event, android-touch-event

It's the first time I am dealing with touch devices, and to implement some basic functions in my website/webapp, I would need to manage touch events.

In the flow of my application, after having dynamically created a div, I attach to it a touchstart event calling a function in which I wish to manage different tasks upon the number of simultaneous touches: in order to do this I thought to use the touchEvent.changedTouches.length property
  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/changedTouches).

I have something like this:

```
$("body").append("<div id='myDiv'>Some text...</div>");
touchEvents();
...
function touchEvents() {
    var touches;
    $("#myDiv").on("touchstart", function (e) {
        touches = e.changedTouches;
        alert(touches.length);
        switch (touches.length) {
            case 1:
            {code_block_1}
            break;
            case 2:
            {code_block_2}
            break;
            default:
            {code_block_default}
        }
    });
}
...
```

When I run it with Safari on Ios (IPad 2), if I touch it with one, two (or more - till 9) finger(s) I get, from alert statement, the correct number of finger(s) used, and the application then correctly runs, if I have done a two finger touch, into the switch case: 2.

But **when I use an Android device** (I tested it with a Samsung and an NGM branded phones - either older and newest Android phones - either with updated Firefox and Chrome) **I always get "1"** by the alert() called just after the touchstart event, **even if I use more than one finger**; consequently the route goes always inside the switch case: 1 option.

I discovered that this seems to be due to a strange behaviour of the touchEvent.touches list.

As a matter of fact, if I have the following code

```
$("body").append("<div id='myDiv'>Some text...</div>");
touchEvents();
...
function touchEvents() {
    var touches;
    $("#myDiv").on("touchstart", function (e) {
        touches = e.touches;
        alert(touches.length);
        ...
    });
}
```

if I touch the surface with 2 fingers (at the same time or one after the other) I always get two alerts!

(when fingers move down one after the other I also get a first alert correctly saying "1")...

The first one (the second in the case the 2 fingers touch is not simultaneous) prompts "2", but immediately after closing this alert, another one is fired prompting "1".

As a check I also tried to copy and past the example code that can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/touches

adding three functions that alert the e.touches.length i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        // Invoke the appropriate handler depending on the
        // number of touch points.
        switch (e.touches.length) {
            case 1: handle_one_touch(e); break;
            case 2: handle_two_touches(e); break;
            case 3: handle_three_touches(e); break;
            default: console.log("Not supported"); break;
        }
    }, false);
    function handle_one_touch(e) {
        touches = e.touches;
        alert(touches.length);
    }
    function handle_two_touch(e) {
        touches = e.touches;
        alert(touches.length);
    }
    function handle_three_touch(e) {
        touches = e.touches;
        alert(touches.length);
    }
});
```

and I always get "1", so it is always called only the handle_one_touch(e) function.

As a consequence, I think, the changedTouches.length property is always "1".

Does someone know if there is a known issue about this matter on Android devices and/or how to solve it?
Thank you in advance, Federico

Comment: did you find an answer? I have the same problem

Comment: Hi Roman, the issue above was related to an old project of mine.
It is more than 2 years that I don't deal anymore with it and with coding in general, but I remember I found the answer to it. Anyway at the moment I don't remember how to fix it. If you are interested, let me know. When I have time I will try to see if I remeber how to do. Cheers